# NSubstitute test failing

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit, nsubstitute

I have a service named MyService which implements IService and my AppContext (inherits from DbContext) gets injected into this service. It has a method called `AddProduct(ProductDTO)` which returns just a Task, as it is just an Insert. I map the input parameter, ProductDTO to Product entity within this method and I call `_appContext.AddAsync(mappedentity)` and `_appcontext.SaveChangesAsync()` within this method.

Now, I have written a unit test case in NSubstitute to add the product by calling the above method in my service. Even though the main app that hits this service method is working just fine and is creating the product, this test case keeps failing with the error "Expected to receive exactly one call. But did not receive any calls".

This is the test case code. I am unsure why this is failing at the first assert on Received. I tried both `Add()` as well as `AddAsync()` and likewise with `SaveChanges`().

```
public class MyServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task AddProduct_ShouldAddProductToContext()
    {
        // Arrange
        var appContext = Substitute.For<IAppContext>();
        var myService = new MyService(appContext);

        var productDTO = new ProductDTO
        {
            // Initialize properties for the ProductDTO
            // ...
        };

        // Act
        await myService.AddProduct(productDTO);

        // Assert
        await appContext.Received(1).Add(Arg.Any<Product>());
        await appContext.Received(1).SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: That would depend entirely on what the implementation of your AddProduct method actually does. What happens when you step into the AddProduct?  Is it creating the Product and calling IAppContext.Add, or are you using the AppContext.Products.Add()? This isn't a great example of unit testing because you are testing implementation, and unless there are attributes within the DTO you have created that affect what happens within AddProduct, what is this code really testing?

Comment: @StevePy. Thanks for your reply. Yes, like I mentioned, it is 4 lines of code in AddProduct(). It maps the dto into the Product entity and then I am doing AppConext.Products.Add() and calling SaveChanges. I don't have any attributes on the DTO.  When I step in, it executes perfectly without any errors. But when the control retuens to the test method, the first assert is failing. When you say, this is not the best way to test it, how else can I test it without actually inserting a row into the database?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I had made was in the asserts. The last two lines need to be replaced with this.

```
await appContext.Products.Received(1).AddAsync(Arg.Any<Product>());
await appContext.Received(1).SaveChangesAsync(true);
```

I was missing true on the SaveChanges and I was not checking the Received on the Products dbset.